# Problem solving a function using FindRoot and then plotting it

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

When I run the following code:

```
xi = -20.; xf = 40.;

stepinter = 0.01;

m = 1/2;

vlogk0s = Re[ParallelTable[
     vks := 
      y /. FindRoot[x == y + 2 m Log[-2 m + y], {y, 2 m + 0.01}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxIterations -> 10000];
     {x, vks}, {x, xi, xf, stepinter}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
rts = Interpolation[vlogk0s];

Plot[rts[x], {x, xi, xf}]
```

[image]
I get the desired plot.

Now I will simply change the function inside the `FindRoot`  as:

```
xi = -20.; xf = 40.;

stepinter = 0.01;

m = 1/2; \[CapitalLambda] = 0.6;

vlogk0sds = Re[ParallelTable[
     vk := 
      y /. FindRoot[
        x == -RootSum[
           6 m - 3 #1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^3 &, (
            Log[y - #1] #1)/(-1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^2) &], {y, 
         2 m + 0.01}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxIterations -> 10000];
     {x, vk}, {x, xi, xf, stepinter}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
rtsds = Interpolation[vlogk0sds];

Plot[rtsds[x], {x, xi, xf}]
```

and the plot becomes messed.

[image]

I already tried different methods in both `FindRoot` and `Interpolation`, I tried different precision, iterations and everything. I know that the plot must be similar to the first one.

**PS:** In case it is needed, the function inside the `FindRoot` may be obtained via:

```
Integrate[(1 - (2 m)/r - \[CapitalLambda]/3 r^2)^-1, r]
```

As input, which yields:

```
-RootSum[6 m - 3 #1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^3 &, (Log[r - #1] #1)/(-1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^2) &]
```

Comment: “ the plot becomes messed” - how exactly? Do you get errors? Warnings? Include an image if it’s not easy to describe.

Comment: I added some pictures, to both cases.

Comment: You might want to ponder the RHS of the equation in `FindRoot`: `Plot[-RootSum[
     6 m - 3 #1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^3 &, (Log[
          y - #1] #1)/(-1 + \[CapitalLambda] #1^2) &] // ReIm // 
  Evaluate, {y, -10, 10}]`

Comment: What do you mean by reconsidering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Michael mentioned in comments was the fact that, When calculating `vlogk0sds`, you are looking for values of $y$ for which your `RootSum` expression is equal to values in the $(-20,40)$ range. However, the following plot of the values of your `RootSum` expression shows that, where the expression is real, its value is *never* negative, and never greater than roughly 12:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate@
    ReIm@
     -RootSum[6 m - 3 #1 + Λ #1^3 &, (Log[y - #1] #1)/(-1 + Λ #1^2) &],
  {y, -10, 20},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Re", "Im"},
  Exclusions -> None
]
```

[image: plot of right hand side of equation]

For instance, there are no values of $y$ for which this expression is equal to $-20$, so the results of `FindRoot` for that value won't be any good. In fact, they won't be much good for *most of* the $x$ values you considered!

---

If you restrict yourself to values for which solutions exist, then the following works quickly, even without parallel evaluation:

```
stepinter = 0.01;
m = 1/2; Λ = 0.6;

vlogk0sds = Chop@
   Table[
     {x, y} /. 
       FindRoot[
         x == -RootSum[6 m - 3 #1 + Λ #1^3 &, (Log[y - #1] #1)/(-1 + Λ #1^2) &], 
         {y, 2 m + 0.01}, AccuracyGoal -> 5
       ],
     {x, 0.01, 12, stepinter}
   ];

ListLogPlot[vlogk0sds, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot of roots and values]

Note that:

1. I use a log plot to emphasize the shape of the curve;
2. it is better to use `Chop` rather than `Re` to remove zero or near-zero imaginary parts resulting from numerical computation so, if the imaginary parts become significant, you are alerted to it;
3. you do not need to interpolate~, then plot: you can plot a list of data points directly using the `ListPlot` family of functions.

Comment: It worked flawlessly, thank you. However, since I am not using interpolation anymore, how do I save it as a function with variable x? Something like func[x]?

Comment: @EdisonSantos You can still use an interpolation for that, just like you did before, if you need it for other purposes. I only wanted to point out that you do not need it *just for plotting*.